# Calculating eigenvectors when eigenvalues is know

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been searching around for a while to find a very simple example which could make it clear for me how to find the eigenvectors, when the eigenvalues is already known. But unfortunately I don't get it.

My question looks like this:

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MlDx.png)

Notice that it has to be by hand with all the steps. I only need to know how to calculate the eigenvectors.

I'm used to do it in Matlab but this is an old exam question so I guess I should learn how to do it by hand as well.

I have been looking in the solution:

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0XJO.png)

But I could use a little bit more explanation than that.

Greetings 
Christian

Comment: Have you looked at your linear algebra book / lecture notes? I honestly don't recall ever seeing one that would not explain this.

Comment: I found this example (https://www.scss.tcd.ie/~dahyotr/CS1BA1/SolutionEigen.pdf), which had what I was looking for. Simple, short with comments. (Maybe a stupid question but looking into math problems 24/7 can make you blind)
Thank you anyone for your help. I appreciate it..

Answer (score 1):

By thefinition, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda$ are the non-null vectors $v$ such that $A.v=\lambda v$. But$$A.v=\lambda v\iff(A-\lambda\operatorname{Id}).v=0.$$That's what is being done in that solution that you posted: for each eigenvalue $\lambda$, the author(s) compute non-null elements of $\ker(A-\lambda\operatorname{Id})$, that is, non-null vectors $v$ such that $(A-\lambda\operatorname{Id}).v=0$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a neat little trick for finding the eigenvectors of a low dimensional matrix. By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem a matrix $A$ satisfies its own characteristic polynomial: $p(A) = 0$, where $p(x) = \det(A - xI)$.

Since the characteristic polynomial's roots are the eigenvalues, this gives $(A - \lambda_1 I)(A - \lambda_2 I)...(A - \lambda_n I) = 0$, where the $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, including multiplicities. Because $A$ commutes with itself and $I$, it doesn't matter what order the eigenvalues are in, so we can take $\lambda_1$ to be which ever eigenvalue you are interested in.

This means that $(A - \lambda_1 I)$ annihilates the product of the other factors, which in turn means it annihilates every column of that product, and therefore any non-zero column must be an eigenvector of $A$ associated with $\lambda_1$.

For example, if $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix with eigenvalues $1, 2, 3$, then the non-zero columns in $(A - 2I)(A - 3I)$ are eigenvectors of $A$ associated with the eigenvalue $1$. The non-zero columns of $(A-I)(A - 3I)$ are eigenvectors associated with $2$, and the non-zero columns of $(A-I)(A-2I)$ are eigenvectors associated with $3$. You can find an example on the [Eigenvalue algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#3%C3%973_matrices) page of Wikipedia.

For larger dimensions, the work of taking all those products gets to be more heavy than alternative methods, but for 2 and 3 dimensions, it is an easy process (once you know the eigenvalues).